# How to spread an object into another without overwriting everything in the object?

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript and currently in the situation where I want to spread a json object into a class based object without overwriting everything in the class object.

The class object (user) has functions and attributes while the json object (items) contains some data of certain fields that I would like to map user.

I have used  the following line of code for object spreading:

```
user = Object.assign({...items });
```

However, the functions in the object and other data fields disappear.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

**Notes:**

- Field names are the same in both objects
- User is a Singleton object

Comment: Why don't you try `Object.assign(user, items)`... and without assigning it back to `user`...??